# Django install/deploy with mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I have xampp on my system. I installed Django also. From last two days I am trying to integrate MySQL with Django. I also tried for Django with xampp but each individual tutorial/process from various links and youtube have failed. Now I can't even run my apache server from xampp.

I also tried Bitnami Django Stack but it clashes with my existing xampp's apache and MySQL ports.

My question is how can I use MySQL(I use xampp for development so I want to use MySQL which is installed with xampp) as a database for Django projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create any database(`DB_NAME`) which you want to use on your Django Project.
2. Edit your settings.py file

   `DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '3306',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWD': '',
   }}`
3. Install the following packages in the virtualenv (if you're using django on virtualenv, which is more preferred):

   `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

   `pip install MySQL-python`
4. That's it!! you have configured Django with MySQL in a very easy way.
5. Now run your Django project:

   `python manage.py migrate`

   `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) dictionary in `settings.py` and point to your mysql server:

> A dictionary containing the settings for all databases to be used with
>   Django. It is a nested dictionary whose contents maps database aliases
>   to a dictionary containing the options for an individual database.

Example:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',      
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'myuserpassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: @AliHayder could you please explain what do you mean by "not working"? What errors do you get?

Comment: Actually I tried that two days ago, however I can memorize that after configuring settings.py when I put the command (python manage.py syncdb) to cmd it gave some log lists error that idicates that mysql is mot working or something like  that.

Comment: @AliHayder then either mysql is not running on the specified host and port, ot database user credentials are wrong, or `DATABASES` settings are not correct. Anyway, show your `DATABASES` setting, thanks.

Comment: thanks, one thing is that my mysql folder is in D:/xampp/mysql and my Django project is in C: Drive, is it creating some problem. I am sure that my mysql port is 3306.

Comment: @AliHayder it actually doesn't matter. Mysql should run as a service on specified host and port.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mysql-python module to make it working

Follow this tutorial to setup mysql in your django environment.

**[SETUP MYSQL WITH DJANGO >>](http://developingable.com/install-mysql-with-django/)**

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for your review, i know it will be good if we can add relevant code snippets in answers, But here my answer is **install mysql-python module** itself, He is not telling anything about his code or other. Thats why i just quoted reason for the problem he experiences, So that he can search for any support for installing mysql-python, And including the whole setup process is little lengthy also.